# Public network spoofing DNS response?

Tags: networking, dns, spoofing

Running `dig @a.nic.ch google.com` whilst connected to some public accessible network I got the following response:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.0 <<>> @a.nic.ch google.com
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59036
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     230 IN  A   142.250.185.238

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 130.59.31.41#53(a.nic.ch) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 14 19:15:08 CEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

Doesn't this mean that DNS responses are getting spoofed since asking the name server with `.ch` shouldn't respond to a `.com` query?

Comment: It might, except 1) you really really want DNS servers to cache the results of DNS queries, and 2) the AUTHORITY: 0 flag indicates that it isn't even claiming to be authoritative.  This server is not claiming to be authoritative; it just claims to know the answer to your question.

Comment: @Slartibartfast: That's kind of the point though: it is *not supposed to* claim to know the answer to this question; most authoritative nameservers, especially TLD nameservers, are configured to refuse to handle arbitrary "outside" queries at all.

Comment: I'll point out your use of the words "supposed to" and "most".  If you research why those are the case, and think about how well those reasons apply to this circumstance / nameserver, and you still think those who run the server made the wrong choice, you might take it up with them.  However, if you just want an authoritative answer to your queries, from servers qualified to provide them, I suggest something like dig +trace www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

When you made your test, it seems that nameserver had not been configured to reject recursive queries from outsiders. Perhaps it was a mistake, as it seems to have been corrected:

```
$ dig @a.nic.ch google.com
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 12189
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
```

Comment: That's not really what I was asking... Apparently the DNS answer got spoofed by the public network I'm in. I don't think that it has to do sth. with the  nameserver's config. as this has occurred to me in several public networks.

Comment: Ah. If the public network implements a *captive portal* system (i.e. all new users are first redirected to some portal page that requires you to at least acknowledge the acceptable use rules before you can use the service), then such spoofing may indeed be part of how the redirection to the portal is actually implemented.

Comment: Alternatively, public networks might be financed by advertising, and such DNS spoofing might be part of an aggressive ad-pushing scheme. "There is no such thing as a free lunch."